# Light patch on tree trunk

Tags: trees, citrus

I have a rather young citrus tree (about 3 years, and been planted here for maybe half a year). I've noticed some weird light patches on the tree trunk, as shown in the image below. They seem to be located only towards the bottom part of the tree. I only noticed it yesterday. It feels wooden like the rest of the tree. It's not wet or anything.

The tree itself looks otherwise very healthy and seems to be passing through a growth spurt of some sort. The weather was very hot recently (36C/97F) and I've been watering it every day.

The only wildlife in the area are cats (I'm wondering whether it's a cat sharpening it's claws on it?)

What could it be?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the greenish streaks? Or something else?

Comment: The yellowish green streaky things yes

Answer (score 1):

We recently had a question about damaged tree bark and it turned out to be a cat.  It was labeled 'What to do about bark damage on a Pistache tree...' June 17  The owner had an arborist go out to inspect.  I'll try to post a link.  But your tree marks do look like cat.  He put a simple wire barrier to protect his tree.

And just FYI, looks like your tree is planted too deeply.  Please pull that soil and mulch back until you are able to see roots.